# cannot see fluent chat option in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I have recently installed fluent chat plugin for one of my customer. I can only see chat icon on front site, but there is no any option visible in wp-admin for configuring fluent chat plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your admin user email address is less then 50 characters. By default the plugin creates a copy of admin user in {db_prefix}_fluentchat_operators table to grant full access to plugin configuration during installation, but the email field has 50 character's limit due to which the installation skips the default entry. I have faced similar issue, see my [comment](https://codecanyon.net/item/fluentchat-wordpress-live-chat/20651073/comments?page=3&filter=all#comment_18434085) here for more details.

**Table structure:**

```
email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
nickname varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
fullname varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
```

You can also increase the limit manually and add user yourself with same email address with admin=1 manually in your table to fix the issue.